# Is there a way to practice with weapons and buildings in Fortnite: Battle Royale?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I'd love to practice building structures or practicing with weapons without worrying about dying before I get a chance to use said weapons.

The problem is, I don't see a way to "practice" in Fortnite Battle Royale.  There's really no chance to practice in a match since shooting wildly gives away your position, or sometimes you just get bad luck and won't get the various other purple/gold tier weapons.

Is there a way to practice with weapons and buildings in Fortnite Battle Royale? Specifically offline?

Comment: Well you could practise a little during the time before the battle bus launches but other players will probably shoot your structure down.

Answer (score 2):

Long answer - Yes. Many players land in the game to win, and get kills - that being the objective of the game. But if you land somewhere with no enemies, you can harvest some materials and practice building. If you want to practice shooting, you could do so in the lobby - there is a small red hitmarker near your crosshair after you've hit someone - or drop right at the end of the Battle Bus' path to kill AFK players.

Another way to improve is trial by fire. Landing in a very populated spot repeatedly (EG: Tilted Towers) will force you to get better to survive. This is a more common method of improving, but it might not be for you.

And no- there is no offline mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lobby to practice shooting and building. Also, there is no offline mode

Answer (score -1):

Short answer - No. The game does not have a PvE at the moment. This is one of the most requested things right now, especially by the new players.

Comment: No PvE mode? What is the Save the World game mode then?

Comment: @TimmyJim Depending on how semantic you want to be, one might even count that as a completely different game. Especialy since Battle Royale is free, but you need to pay to get into Save the World (I think).

Comment: While STW and BR are very different if you want to practice building then STW would do the trick. Practicing with weapons is a little trickier since you have to get said weapons first. And of course the pay wall makes it not an ideal solution either...